# Making a Memphis pattern

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

How could I make this a Memphis material from the picture?

[image]

Comment: Please Clarify.  01. Are you trying to create tileable seamless images from scratch?   02.  Place the finished images above on a Mesh object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you first must make sure that the object you want to put the texture on is unwrapped.

Then, make sure you are in cycles render and add a new image texture shown below

[image]

If you ever want to change how big the texture looks on your object, just scale your UV mesh up or down.

[image]

Comment: I am suggesting that you actually place those images on the cube in your answer above.  If you have the time and energy.